# gdal_translate called via subprocess.check_output works when called directly, but not from within arcgis

Tags: arcpy, python, gdal-translate, python-toolbox, subprocess

EDIT: Solved it myself. Beginners error... :/

I am writing a python Toolbox that should use gdal_translate to convert an ASCII Gridded XYZ-File into a lower resolution (and doing afterwards a couple of other things).

For that I have written the following snippet:

```
filepath=r'X:\some_path\to\file\with_only_ascii_and_no_whitespaces\file.xyz'
try:
    inf=filepath
    outf=filepath + '__dgm20.xyz'
    result = subprocess.check_output(
        [
            'gdal_translate', 
            '-of', 
            'XYZ', 
            '-tr',
            '20',
            '20', 
            inf.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding()), 
            outf.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
        ], 
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
    arcpy.AddWarning(unicode(err))
    arcpy.AddWarning(err.cmd)
    arcpy.AddError(err.output)
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage(filepath + '__dgm20.xyz')
    arcpy.AddMessage(result)
```

When I run this from the python console in cmd.exe or the ArcGIS python console, everything is fine, my file will be created. But when I run it from within a python toolbox (after retrieving filepath from a parameter and normalizing it with os.path) I get this error:

> ERROR 1: At line 3999971, found 1 tokens. Expected 3 at least

The processed file (filepath) ist totally fine, I think.

So, why is this happening? What is it I can't figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem myself. But sadly it wasn't caused by the code snippet I provided.

The indentation was the problem. The csv hasn't been fully written down, when i tried to start working with it in gdal_translate.

```
filepath=r'X:\some_path\to\file\with_only_ascii_and_no_whitespaces\file.xyz'
with open(filepath, 'r') as xyzfile:
    with open(filepath + '.txt', 'wb') as csvfile:
        dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(xyzfile.read(2048), " ")
        xyzfile.seek(0)
        df = pandas.read_csv(xyzfile, dialect=dialect, header=None)
        df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
        f = df.columns.values.tolist()
        df = df.sort_values(by=[f[1], f[0]])
        df.to_csv(csvfile, index=None, header=['x','y','z'])

        try: #here starts the above snippet
            inf=filepath + '.txt'
            outf=filepath + '__dgm20.xyz'
            [...]
```

correct is:

```
filepath=r'X:\some_path\to\file\with_only_ascii_and_no_whitespaces\file.xyz'
with open(filepath, 'r') as xyzfile:
    with open(filepath + '.txt', 'wb') as csvfile:
        [...]
try:
    inf=filepath + '.txt'
    outf=filepath + '__dgm20.xyz'
    result = subprocess.[...]
```

Sorry for any caused loss of time.